# Nested array key syntax

Tags: php, arrays

This is probably very basic and I'm most likely overthinking it, but I'm working from a class ([Zip/Postal Code Lookup Class](http://www.bluefrog.ca/2011/03/zippostal-code-lookup-class/)). The script's array goes like so :

```
$myinput = 'G9A 5Z7'; // my zip code -> will later be loaded from a database
print_r($lookup->query($myinput));
```

And returns :

```
Array ( [PostalCode] => G9A5Z7 [City] => TROIS-RIVIERES [Province] => QC [Country] => CA [AreaCode] => 819 [TimeZone] => 5 [Coordinates] => Array ( [Latitude] => 46.332057 [Longitude] => -72.557197 ) )
```

The information is correct -- that is not a problem. Where I need help is how to obtain the key `Latitude` and its value of `46.332057`.

This is most likely a syntax problem, I've tried options like so :

```
echo $lookup->query($myinput)[Coordinates][Longitude];
echo $lookup->query($myinput)['Coordinates']['Latitude'];
echo $lookup->query[$myinput]['Coordinates']['Latitude'];
echo $lookup->query([$myinput]['Coordinates']['Latitude']);
```

I'm running out of ideas -- any clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just toss the square brackets at the end of a function call.  You need to store the results into a variable and then access the elements of the results array.

Use this instead:

```
$results = $lookup->query[$myinput];
echo $results['Coordinates']['Latitude'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the result of `$lookup->query` to an array.  Then access the value from the array like this:

```
$result_array = $lookup->query($myinput);
echo $result_array['Coordinates']['Latitude'];
```